# Adaptar la hora en SQL teniendo en cuenta el cambio de hora (verano/invierno)

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql

Tengo un pequeño problema, trabajo sobre un programa que genera unos registros y guarda la hora (en SQL) sin tener en cuenta el UTC, es decir ahora mismo en España estamos en UTC +2 (horario de verano) pero cuando vuelve el invierno pasamos a UTC +1.

Pues bien, estoy trabajando en un pequeño programa para crear informes sobre estos registros, pero me estoy encontrando con dificultades para tratar las horas para que se adapte a la hora en la que se generó ese registro.

Es decir si un registro se hizo en invierno (UTC +1), supongamos que a las 09:00, pues en base de datos queda registrado a las 08:00.

Pero si este registro se ha hecho en verano (UTC +2), a la misma hora las 09:00, en base de datos queda registrado a las 07:00.

No es problema que no tenga en cuenta el UTC a la hora de generar el registro siempre y cuando yo pueda tratarlo correctamente.

Yo estoy intentando tratar las horas con la función:

```
SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,**HORA AQUI**)
```

Esto aplica automáticamente el UTC de la zona horaria, pero claro el UTC actual en verano es +2, pero si un registro se hizo en invierno no quiero que le aplique +2, porque acaba saliendo una hora de más, yo quiero que le aplique un UTC +1.

Sabéis de alguna función parecida a la que estoy utilizando pero que aplique el UTC en cuestión a cuando se realizó el registro?

Si no se me ocurría mirar de crear alguna función que tenga en cuenta la fecha en la que se hizo el registro pero creo que es algo rebuscado.

No se si queda claro el problema que tengo, espero que sí y me podáis ayudar para tratar estas horas.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Déjame ver si entendí tu problema,tienes un servidor al que no le han actualizado la zona horaria con los cambios de verano/invierno, por lo que llegada una determinada fecha, la fecha hora que figura en las tablas debería ajustarse una X cantidad de horas. ¿Es así?